# annotations in gwt

Tags: gwt, annotations

It is possible to create simple annotation for GWT client which give me possibility to use on client side:

`@NewAnnotation`

`myClass myObject`

instead of:

`myClass myObject=new myClass();`

Answer (score 6):

This is essentially the pattern used by UiBinder.  The way to implement this behavior is to [write a Generator](http://vinaytech.wordpress.com/2008/10/01/gwt-generator-why-do-at-runtime-what-you-can-do-at-compile-time/) that produces the glue code to assign values to the fields.

You would be able to write something like:

```
class MyClass {
  @NewAnnotation
  SomeType field;

  interface MyFieldFiller extends FieldFiller<MyClass> {}
  MyClass() {
    GWT.create(MyFieldFiller.class).populate(this);
  }
}
```

You might want to look at [GIN](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) instead, which already implements a very robust dependency-injection mechanism.